# Coundown cokie set up

Tags: javascript

I cant figuret how set cookie for my countdownt timeer, that if i refresh page it vill not disapear but vill counting.
i be glad if eny can help. i use jquery 2.1.4 and this java countdown script, but when i refresh page all my coundown timers are lost!

```js
/**
 * Created by op on 18.07.2015.
 */

function leadZero (n)
{
 n = parseInt(n);
 return (n < 10 ? '0' : '') + n;
}

function startTimer(timer_id) {
 var timer = $(timer_id);
 var time = timer.html();
 var arr = time.split(":");
 var h = arr[0];
 h = h.split(" / ");
 h = h[1];
 var m = arr[1];
 var s = arr[2];
 if (s == 0)
 {
  if (m == 0)
  {
   if (h == 0)
   {
    timer.html('')
    return;
   }
   h--;
   m = 60;
  }
  m--;
  s = 59;
 }
 else
 {
  s--;
 }
 timer.html(' / '+leadZero(h)+":"+leadZero(m)+":"+leadZero(s));
 setTimeout(function(){startTimer(timer_id)}, 1000);
}

function timer (name, time)
{
 var timer_name = name;
 var timer = $(timer_name);
 var time_left = time;
 timer.html(' / '+ time);
 startTimer(timer_name);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.fid').click(function (e)
 {
  var timer_name = '.timer_'+$(this).data('fid');
  var timer = $(timer_name);
  if (timer.html() == '')
  {
   var time_left = timer.data('timer');
   var hours = leadZero(Math.floor(time_left / 60));
   var minutes = leadZero(time_left % 60);
   var seconds = '00';
   timer.html(' / '+hours+':'+minutes+':'+seconds);
   startTimer(timer_name);
  }
 });

 $.each($('.tab'), function () {
  $(this).click(function () {
   $.each($('.tab'), function() {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
   });
   $(this).addClass('active');
   $('.list').hide();
   $('#content-'+$(this).attr('id')).show();
  });
 });

 if (window.location.hash != '')
 {
  var tab = window.location.hash.split('-');
  tab = tab[0];
  $(tab).click();
 }

 console.log(window.location.hash)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you actually [set a cookie.](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

Setting the cookie would go like:

```
document.cookie="timer=" + time;
```

And then call it at the beginning of your code

```
var time = getCookie("timer");
```

The `getCookie()` function is outlined in that link, as well as a base knowledge about them.

Comment: sorry you can tell where i need put this code? i dont know where i need put in this!